# How to groupby in python without pandas

Tags: python, aggregate, grouping

I would need your help for this issue . I have tried to look around but i couldn't get anything wanted. I also do not want to use pandas.
I have found a small example and it did work very well. but when I applied it on my data , it doesn't work and it doesn't do the grouping. Any idea where it could come from? I'd be so grateful ...

Here are my data and output :

```
liste_of_values =
    [[0, 0, 'sv_SE', 'SE', 'Tarket', '04/18/2021'],
     [1, 0, 'en_EU', 'EU', 'Tarket', '04/18/2021'],
     [2, 0, 'en_EU', 'EU', 'Tarket', '04/18/2021'],
     [3, 0, 'en_EU', 'EU', 'Tarket', '04/18/2021'],
     [4, 0, 'en_EU', 'EU', 'Tarket', '04/18/2021'],
     [5, 0, 'en_EU', 'EU', 'Tarket', '04/18/2021'],
     [7, 0, 'en_EU', 'EU', 'Tarket', '04/18/2021'],
     [8, 1, 'sv_SE', 'SE', 'Tarket', '04/18/2021'],
     [9, 1, 'sv_SE', 'SE', 'Tarket', '04/18/2021'],
     [10, 0, 'en_EU', 'EU', 'Tarket', '04/18/2021'],
     [11, 1, 'sv_SE', 'SE', 'Tarket', '04/18/2021'],
     [12, 0, 'en_EU', 'EU', 'Tarket', '04/18/2021'],
     [13, 0, 'en_EU', 'EU', 'Tarket', '04/18/2021'],
     [14, 0, 'en_EU', 'EU', 'Tarket', '04/18/2021'],
     [15, 0, 'en_EU', 'EU', 'Tarket', '04/18/2021'],
     [16, 0, 'en_EU', 'EU', 'Tarket', '04/18/2021'],
     [17, 0, 'en_EU', 'EU', 'Tarket', '04/18/2021'],
     [18, 0, 'en_EU', 'EU', 'Tarket', '04/18/2021'],
     [19, 0, 'en_EU', 'EU', 'Tarket', '04/18/2021'],
     [20, 0, 'en_EU', 'EU', 'Tarket', '04/18/2021'],
     [21, 0, 'en_EU', 'EU', 'Tarket', '04/18/2021'],
     [22, 0, 'en_EU', 'EU', 'Tarket', '04/18/2021']]

groupby =[[k, sum(int(v[1]) for v in g)] for k, g in groupby(list_of_values, key = lambda x: (x[3], x[4], x[5]))]

OUTPUT :

[[('SE', 'Tarket', '04/18/2021'), 0],
 [('EU', 'Tarket', '04/18/2021'), 0],
 [('SE', 'Tarket', '04/18/2021'), 2],
 [('EU', 'Tarket', '04/18/2021'), 0],
 [('SE', 'Tarket', '04/18/2021'), 1],
 [('EU', 'Tarket', '04/18/2021'), 0]]
```

Here is the example I found (that works) :

```
from itertools import groupby
data = [['Dave', 3, 'Red'], ['Dave', 4, 'Red'], ['Dave', 2, 'Blue'], ['Sue', 4, 'Red'], ['Sue', 1, 'Red'], ['Sue', 3, 'Yellow']]
projuserDays=[[k, sum(v[1] for v in g)] for k, g in groupby(data, key = lambda x: (x[0], x[2]))]

OUTPUT: 

[[('Dave', 'Red'), 7],
 [('Dave', 'Blue'), 2],
 [('Sue', 'Red'), 5],
 [('Sue', 'Yellow'), 3]]
```

thank you so much

Comment: What is your expected output? What do you want to do with a single group?

Comment: Make sure the data is `sorted` by the same key before doing `itertools.groupby`

Comment: You might notice the different groups occur when any key value changes. The first sentence in the documentation states "Make an iterator that returns *consecutive* keys and groups from the iterable.". You may want to sort by language code (and the other keys) first.

Comment: for `itertools.groupby` to work, your data must be sorted. As noted in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), `groupby()` only groups _consecutive keys_ together (I am paraphrasing), and **"...which is why it is usually necessary to have sorted the data using the same key function"**.

Comment: I'm curious why you don't want to use Pandas.

Comment: my boss isn't a very big fan of pandas and he rather us (his subordinates) to do it without using it @00

Comment: Unfortunate. I guess that happens. I hope you don't have to deal (much) with lists of hundreds of thousands of items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `itertools.groupby` you will have to sort the data by the same key before grouping:

```
>>> key = lambda x: (x[3], x[4], x[5])                                      
>>> [[k, sum(int(v[1]) for v in g)] for k, g in groupby(sorted(list_of_values, key=key), key=key)]                                                  
[[('EU', 'Tarket', '04/18/2021'), 0], [('SE', 'Tarket', '04/18/2021'), 3]]
```